# Can it be proved that the integrand is integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let
‎$x(t) \in \mathbb{R}$‎
be a continuous and derivable function. If we prove that the function $$f(\tau)=\frac{(x(t)-x(\tau))^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha+1}} , \alpha>0$$ is integrable, it can be shown that the following relation is established 
$$
\begin{equation}
‎ \int_{0}^{t} \frac{(x(t)-x(\tau))^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha+1}}  \,d\tau \geq 0‎.
‎\end{equation}‎
$$
 Can this result be obtained? In other words, it can be shown that $f$ is integrable?

Comment: That depends on what $x(\cdot)$ is...

Comment: we know that $x(.)$ is continuous and derivable function.

Comment: can you give an example that f is not integrable.

Comment: You cannot expect f to be integrable for all values of $\alpha >0$. For example take $x(t)=t$ for all t. In this case f is integrable (on finite intervals containing 0) if and only if $\alpha <2$.

Comment: How to do this? 0< $\alpha$ <1 ...

Answer (score 0):

The integral is improper at $\tau=t$. Since $x$ is differentiable at $t$, we have
$$
\frac{(x(t)-x(\tau))^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha+1}}\sim\frac{(x'(t))^2\,(t-\tau)^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha+1}}\sim\frac{(x'(t))^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha-1}}.
$$
If $x'(t)\ne0$, this is integrable at $t$ if and only if $\alpha<2$. You can get a larger range of integrability at those $t$'s with $x'(t)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... May you explain a value about the equivalence?

Comment: Definition of differentiability: if $f(t)$ is differentiable at $t=a$ then $f(t)=f(a)+f'(a)(t-a)+o(t-a)$.